# R: Statistical tests for cluster analysis?

Tags: r, clustering

I'm not even sure if this is a well-formed question, but here it goes:

Let's say I have three variables (shape, size, and color), and I want to test whether those three dimensions describe uniquely distinct clusters that differentially predict some other variable (say sales amount).   What kind of statistical tests / tools would allow such a comparison?  Are there good references for this kind of analysis?

Comment: Could you use a classification tree with cluster grouping as your response and see which variable (shape, size, and color) explains the most variance (greatest reduction in variance)?

Comment: What do you mean by "those three dimensions describe uniquely distinct clusters"? It's bog-ordinary to see if 3 variables predict some other variable. You seem to have inserted something else in between. Is what you're doing the following: (1) cluster 3D predictor data; (2) assign observations to formed clusters; (3) use assigned cluster membership to predict sales?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no tests of hypothesis for this kind of thing.  From Elements of Statistical Learning:

> In the context of unsupervised learning, there is no such direct measure of success. It is difficult to ascertain the validity of inferences drawn from the output of most unsupervised learning algorithms. One must resort to heuristic arguments not only for motivating the algorithms, as is often the case in supervised learning as well, but also for judgments as to the quality of the results.  (p.g. 487 of the second edition)

If you want to use those variables to predict sales, that is a supervised problem, and a different question all together.  For cluster analysis, you need to analyze the validity of the results in another way (say, within cluster distance, or a silhouette plot)

Comment: This is very helpful.  Do you have recommendations on fast clustering algorithms in big datasets (e.g. >300,000 rows) in R such that also permit visualization?

Comment: I don't have a comprehensive overview.  I just ran KMeans with 300,000 rows on my iMac and it didn't hiccup.  Most software should be able to handle that.  For viz, I would recommend you cluster, then sample the data. Visualizing all the data isn't necessary.  If you found this helpful, please mark the answer as accepted.  If you have more questions, feel free to ask.

Comment: Sorry! Forgot to checkmark.  Extremely helpful answer.  I may be coming back to this if I have any trouble.  Thanks so much for your help!